# Why is my boostrap popover content now showing?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a Bootstrap popover on my website but only the title display leaving the content out.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" title="popover title" data-content="Come">
   Popover
</button>
```

Comment: did you have any luck fixing this? did you try my code (below)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="popover title" data-bs-content="Come">Popover</button>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
</script>
```

works for me